# android save settings and information

Tags: android, xml, sqlite, saving-data

i am new to android, i searched a lot and couldn't find a satisfying answer; what i need is to save some setting for my application such as

1> language, number of items to display, display/not display images, etc...
which i think is best done using  the shared preferences

2> save which data categories to get from the internet...

here is my problem:

i have data divided into category objects with key, name, type, data[]...(data[] is changing all the time and not saved after exiting the application),(key, name, type are final values defined by programmer).

and because there are many categories which the user may or may not want to load(around 25), he/she can choose which categories to display, and these choices must be saved.

i think using shared preferences will not help because of the complexity of the data; i was thinking of using sqlite or xml, not sure which is the best choice keeping in mind efficiency and memory size.

note: i am using a global variable for the category information array, that is because data[] needs to be refreshed automatically every 2-3 minutes and must be available to all activities also efficiency and memory space are an issue.
i will appreciate any advice, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1> SharedPreferences is the right choice

2> you have multiple possibilities

a) Use the internal storage and use Object Serialization (for simplicity reasons), xml (if you want to exchange the data) or use a own format

b) SQLite is the fastest solution. But you have to do more programming for that

---

b would be my choice, so create a DB-Object (static or singleton pattern) and write functions for every database task

Comment: thank you; what i need is: when launching the application, i will check for the category read flag and accordingly read and display data[], also in category settings activity the user choose to set read to true/false and save. but no other variables modified.

Comment: from what i found: serialization- it is very slow, xml comes with parsing problems...i think i will go with your suggestion for using sqlite- the data is best formatted and thread safe. also i will need in the future to save some data in the database as favorites chosen by the user. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, SharedSettings should help youy. There is plenty information around, but post back if you are lost.

2) I would make a table with all the categories and a boolean value thats says "show" where you can keep if the user wants to show it or not.

Of course it depends on the size of the categories and how much they change, because otherwise you will be updating the database forever.

Comment: thank you; do you mean by table using sqlite table? for the size of categories: key and name only need to be saved along with the show flag, and these values will not change they are set once by programmer, they are not dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

User shared preference in store your setting,

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.applicationContext.getSharedPreferences(preferencesName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    //For saving the setting:    


        //for storing long
              SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        editor.putLong(key, value);
        //for storing string                editor.commit();
              SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        editor.putString(key, value);
                        editor.commit();
        //and similarly for int,float etc


        //For Retrieving the string:

            sharedPreferences.getLong(key, defaultValue); //for long value 
            sharedPreferences.getSting(key, defaultValue); //for string value
```